# Two Ionic 3 Apps with the same OneSignal App ID + Laravel Server

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, onesignal

I am developing a Uber-like project using Ionic 3. There is an app for the passenger and another one for the driver. Both need to subscribe to OneSignal notifications.

The problem happens when my Laravel server needs to deliver a notification: Both apps have the same OneSignal player ID (based on the device instead of app id), that is, a notification that should be handled by the passenger can be sent to the driver, if both apps are installed on the same device.

So, I need help to know the best way to overcome this problem:

- Create another OneSignal app and find a way to make my Laravel server choose which ONESIGNAL_APP_ID and ONESIGNAL_REST_API_KEY to send the notifications to the right app. (Practical, but I'm not sure if this is possible).
- Generate another OneSignal Player ID for one of the apps by changing the OneSignal plugin source code. (This solution sounds very stupid, but would solve everything at once)
- Make app 1 open app 2 if notification should be sent to app 2. Find a way to pass notification information between apps (deep links?) and make app 2 treat the received information as it was the original notification. (It would be necessary to make it work on Android as well as on iOS. Would it be worth it?)
- Just use a service for push notifications that can send the notification based on app id and re-configure the Laravel server.

Which one would be the best alternative? Can there be another one?

Comment: I go with the first one

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use Tags. In driver app you will do something like this.

```
this.oneSignal.sendTag("driver", "true");
this.oneSignal.sendTag("passenger", "false");
```

and for passenger :

```
this.oneSignal.sendTag("driver", "false");
this.oneSignal.sendTag("passenger", "true");
```

Comment: I'm already using tags, but when I open the driver app, the OneSignal user for my device receives the tag "driver". When I open the passenger app, the tag changes to "passenger" for the same user. I need two different users.

Comment: so in this case you can send tag like this. this.oneSignal.sendTag("{appId : "xxxxxxxx", passenger" : "true", "driver", "false"}); or the driver need to have another phone. because you will have the same playerid